# MVC2 Url with a dash

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view (page) called DataGrowth.aspx, how can I display it in the browser like so:

http://localhost/Solutions/Data-Growth/

Trying to do this with ASP.Net MVC2

Thanks

Comment: You mean how do you define a controller action method with a dash in it? It's unrelated to the view filename. Or are you using the default action to display named pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add an

```
[ActionName("Data-Growth")]
```

attribute to the Controller Action.
You can then choose to rename your View to Data-Growth.aspx or simply modify your return statement to

```
return View("DataGrowth");
```